# Xcode Signing Failed Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've been reading on "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1" and haven't come to solution. Has anyone familiar with this error, please I need help : (

```
CodeSign /Users/beetsoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bimrfbszzyhuecbvvjcicqjtcsqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/plantapp.app
    cd /Users/beetsoft/TIA/ARSystem/Builds/iOS
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Distribution: pocket queries, Inc. (PXS8PN3EZZ)"
Provisioning Profile: "plantapp_dis"
                      (b7ae657e-8ceb-4d15-8ba3-889429c28b48)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 0789673E756258B64241FC3775D466CAB50D728D --entitlements /Users/beetsoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bimrfbszzyhuecbvvjcicqjtcsqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/plantapp.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/beetsoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bimrfbszzyhuecbvvjcicqjtcsqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/plantapp.app

/Users/beetsoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bimrfbszzyhuecbvvjcicqjtcsqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/plantapp.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to run on a device? or archiving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, if you are running on a device it gives this error because of the following reason:

The signing identity of provisioning profile you are using is Distribution profile as I can see from this error:

```
Signing Identity: "iPhone Distribution: pocket queries, Inc. (PXS8PN3EZZ)" Provisioning Profile: "plantapp_dis" (b7ae657e-8ceb-4d15-8ba3-889429c28b48
```

**Distribution provisioning profiles** are meant to use for archieving and distributing it to **Appstore**. Not for running on a device. You need to use **development provisioning profile** for that purpose.

You can change your provisioning profile in **build settings -> code signing identity** or
**General->Automatic code signing**

Comment: Thank you very much. I did check and reassign those values. It's working now!!

Comment: please check..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378604/xcode9-code-sign-error-in-ionic3-project-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with

Comment: Please click on project file from left side project navigator menu. You will have build settings option

Answer (score 1):

For me, updating Xcode and Mac OSX to the latest version solved the signing issues.

Answer (score 0):

CHECK

- Xcode! Check your **certificate** on "Target" -> "Build Setting" -> "Code Signing Identity"
- Xcode! Check your **provisioning** profile on "Target" -> "Build Setting" -> "Provisioning"
- Keychain! Check your **certificate** have **private key**
- Check your **provisioning** that create from **certificate** or not?

Restart Xcode Clean and Build again hope you ok

Comment: Thank you very much. I did check and change everything to automatic.
Everything works now!!

Comment: please check..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378604/xcode9-code-sign-error-in-ionic3-project-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

1) Run "keychain access"

2) Select keychain with your development certificate

3) Lock it (through menu) and then unlock it

4) Voilá! It should work