# xcode9 - Code Sign Error in ionic3 project，Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

After I update IOS in my ionic3 project, I did like this [my stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309992/missing-marketing-icon-ios-cordova/48337918#48337918), then when I want to running in my device by xcode, showing this error for me.

error showing: (in `.xcworkspace`)

```
/Users/zzm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/民安-马来西亚-dihlpydipawmqvehhrmobufggotw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/民安-马来西亚.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: Please link full build.log

Comment: @Frix33 Thats too long, sri.. Did you mean build.log showing when I running 'ionic cordova build ios --prod'?

Comment: That is pod issue now. please check pod name you are using in your podfile

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I am using OngSignal plugin in my project.. before I update IOS, no error showing when I am running my project in `.xcworkspace`

Comment: I'm bit confused. Kindly add any screenshot what error you are getting. I may help you

Comment: @SivajeeBattina `/Users/zzm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/民安-马来西亚-dihlpydipawmqvehhrmobufggotw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/民安-马来西亚.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`
This is my error

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I UPDATE that was just tried.. because in my project i am using pod already, so cannot running in `.xcodeproj`, but i have no idea how to solve so just try erveything

Comment: Do you know where to change project settings? If you don't know please go to project navigator and click on project name. It will show project related settings. In that select build settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163688/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-sivajee-battina).

Comment: Please note that once you are using podfile, don't run from .xcodeproj, you will get workspace. run .xcworkspace

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Sri I try to set it in code signing there, but still showing error for me

Comment: @YuyangHe, in second screenshot, it says lPods library not compiled. Don't open xcodeproj, instead open xcworkspace, because this project using Pods library...Code sign is another problem.

Comment: @Guru check first screen shot please

Comment: I deleted UPDATE text already

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Could you help me check again?

Comment: After changing the code Signing identities what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Please check my update, is it change like that?

Comment: Change provisioning profile from Automatic to specific provisioning profile you have. and then change Debug, AnyiOSSDK values to corresponding developer certificate

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Could you come into discussion room, please

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I update screenshot in my question

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Thank you very much.. error solved and I write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't know why, I just restart my MAC, then error solved.

Reference:
[Install on Device give Error : Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750154/install-on-device-give-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)