# xcode / flutter Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, flutter

I've been trying to run my flutter project in iOS for 2 days now with no luck becouse of this "code sign" error. I tried to search online but nothing is working.
What i have tried to so far is 
1. Uninstall xCode and flutter and install it again
2. Clean Xcode
3. tried different tips from the comments on this post : [Xcode Signing Failed Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446828/xcode-signing-failed-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
This is the output of error in xcode console.

```
    CodeSign /Users/user2020/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epqpftwmoicslfeecsrrgqoweeja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExitNews.app
        cd /Users/user2020/Documents/LatestApp/ios
        export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    Signing Identity:     "-"

        /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/user2020/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epqpftwmoicslfeecsrrgqoweeja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/ExitNews.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/user2020/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epqpftwmoicslfeecsrrgqoweeja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExitNews.app

    /Users/user2020/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epqpftwmoicslfeecsrrgqoweeja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExitNews.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the problem in the KeyChain 
A quick fix is to write this code in the Terminal at bash

```
xattr -cr .
```